# Unable to connect to Mikrotik 5G after changing wifi card

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, iwlwifi

I have an ASUS TUF A17 (FA706IU) and my wifi card stopped working, I decided to replace it with another one and I changed it to Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 M.2 2.4Gbps 802.11ax Bluetooth 5.3 (AX210NGW). But now I'm unable to connect to 5G  Mikrotik wifi. I'm saying Mikrotik here because I have an older router tp-link and I'm able to connect 2.4 & 5 GHz but only 2.4 GHz Mikrotik. For Windows 11 everything works fine so the card is able to do it, I guess something wrong with the drivers I tried to install driver from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html but id didn't help. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04

upd: Tried `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 wd_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` It helped to connect but the speed was awful.

upd: for some reasons speed dropped again, even when I removed password at all[image][image]

UPD:
Well, I'm 99.99% sure that Mikrotik misconfigured, when I changed it to 20/40/80MHz Ceee from 20/40/80MHz XXXX it started working with encryption pretty fast. Hope it will be useful for somebody or somebody will advice something better!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with changing wpa2 psk to wpa psk on Mikrotik side.

Upd: speed was awful, so I enabled encryption to normal wpa2 and changed Channel Width from 20/40/80MHz XXXX to 20/40/80MHz Ceee and now it works

Comment: Note that WPA is not secure. It can be cracked!

Comment: Yes, but at least now I know what to fix